# Visual studio can't see Anaconda's modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, numpy, anaconda

I have 2 Python environments (Python 3.6 by Visual studio 2017 and Python 3.7 by Anaconda)

When I run a script I get an error that *import numpy*

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from . import multiarray ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\projects\UdacityNanoDegreeCourse\UdacityNanoDegreeCourse\LearningCurves\LearningCurves.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       import numpy as np   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line
>   142, in 
>       from . import add_newdocs   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from numpy.lib import add_newdoc   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib__init__.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from .type_check import *   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       import numpy.core.numeric as _nx   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most likely you are trying to import a
>   failed build of numpy. If you're working with a numpy git repo, try
>   `git clean -xdf` (removes all files not under version control). 
>   Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.

As a temporary fix I run Visual Studio from Anaconda prompt.

How can I fix the environment so that I could run Visual Studio as usually by double click? Do I need to change PATH somehow?

**Right click-> Activate Environment didn't help either.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it myself

In the PATH variable

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts

should go first